# After adding custom css in a page browser change the whole css after updating that page

Tags: html, css

> I wrote this CSS in WordPress website for a button. But after updating
> I saw that the button got a new animation for which I did not write
> any css. Then I inspect that and saw there was new `keyframe` added.

**CSS I wrote-**

```
a.eael-creative-button.eael-creative-button--ujarak {
    animation: pulse infinite 2s;
}


@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(253 253 253 / 70%);
}

70% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgb(255 232 0 / 0%);
}

100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(255 232 0 / 0%);
}

}
```

****After updating the css I found in inspection mode-****

```
 a.eael-creative-button.eael-creative-button--ujarak {
        animation: pulse infinite 2s;
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
        0%, 100% {
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    }

    50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05,1.05,1.05);
    }
```

Here the `Keyframes` got changed automatically after updating the page. Why this happening? Anyone knows the solution please?

Comment: Please add the HTML code.

Comment: It could possibly coming from browser's default css. Please check the inpector to see from where the css is coming.. Each css should have the corresponding filename with link on top-right corner ( in the area where you're seeing the applied css )

Comment: Change the name of keyframe from pulse to anything else. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You've got a clash with some existing CSS in the WordPress site. It's not that the extra CSS attributes were added automatically, but rather that there is already a `pulse` animation defined. Try calling it something different.

Comment: Thanks, after changing the name of animation its now working. Thanks a lot